# join two columns of different dataframes into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

one:

```
[A]
 1

 2

 3
```

two:

```
[B]
 7

 6

 9
```

How can I join two columns of different dataframes into another dataframe?

Like that:

```
[A][B]
 1  7

 2  6

 3  9
```

I already tried that:

```
result = A
result = result.rename(columns={'employee_id': 'A'})
result['B'] = pd.Series(B['employee_id'])
```

and

```
B_column = B["employee_id"]
result = pd.concat([result,B_column], axis = 1)
result
```

but I still couldn't

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {"A" : range(1, 4)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {"B" : range(7, 10)})
df = df1.join(df2)
```

Gives

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 9 |

Comment: returned however with only 3 rows

Comment: @FelipeCristiano It's an identical output to what you asked for in your question

Answer (score 0):

While there is various way to accomplish this, one way would be to just merge them on the index.
Something like this:

```
dfResult = dfA.merge(dfB, left_on=dfA.index, right_on=dfB.index, how='inner')
```

Comment: this returned: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'

Comment: That means you are using series data,  But in question, you are saying its dataframe